# My affiliation after I moved to another institution for Ph.D

Tags: phd, paper-submission, authorship, affiliation

I did my Master's in A university and then moved on to B for my Ph.D.

Covid outbreak started about the time when I was wrapping up my project, I had most of my manuscript done and was pending for iterative feedbacks from my advisor at A university. Due to COVID, my project got pushed back from priority and now, as a Ph.D. student at B university, I'm re-working my manuscripts to submit to an academic journal.

I don't know what to do with my affiliation in this situation. Should I list mine as of B university? Or should it still be A?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the work was done at affiliation A and your adviser for that project was at affiliation A, and now you are at affiliation B. I disagree with Buffy's answer, which is to list your affiliation as B rather than A.

The most common approach is to put affiliation A with a footnote that says: "**Present address: affiliation B**", or to put both affiliation A and B.

You might also like to ask your advisers at affiliation A and B whether or not to include those affiliations on your paper, so that neither adviser can get angry at you for doing what they don't want you to do or not doing what they do want you to do.

Comment: This may be field dependent, but in my field you definitely always put your *current* affiliation and add a footnote if the majority of the work was done elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Generally your affiliation is the institution with which you are *currently* employed or a student. University A is a "prior affiliation", unless you still have some formal relationship with them.

Your dissertation/project/manuscript may need to *acknowledge* A for any support for research leading to a paper, but your affiliation should be B.

The acknowledgement can, of course, take the form ... "much of the work was done when I was affiliated with A...".

The same would be true if *all* of the work was done at A. You *were* affiliated with them. But no longer.

---

If people want to find you, they want to start looking at the place you list as your affiliation. Going backwards in time is much easier than going forwards since B may not have an easy way to point people to you at A. But listing prior affiliations as needed helps go in the other direction.

Comment: Hmm, in contrast - Unless it was quite a long delay (several years)  - in my field I would expect that students or postdocs would use the affiliation of the institution where majority of the work was done or was supposed to have been done. Then, use a footnote that specifies the current address. In any case, if there are senior co-authors, it is best to talk to them. They may have strong opinions, particularly if they were funding the work.

Comment: @Carol +1 for your comment. Did you see my answer about 8 minutes before your comment? I mentioned the same two things: (1) usually the affiliation where most of the work was done is used, (2) but it's best to also ask the supervisors.

Comment: See Carol comment and especially the other answer. That it is the way, unless same strategy playing of the supervisors/universities.

Answer (score 2):

In my field (physics) we put both affiliations and we do not necessarily specify which is the current one, which I guess is not very smart. This would probably be acceptable

> Leo Yoon<sup>a,b</sup>
>
> <sup>a</sup>Previous affiliation, <sup>b</sup>Current affiliation
>
> *Email*: leo.yoon@affiliation.current.edu

So they know where to find you and your former institution gets proper credit. Depending on the field it could also be appropriate to just acknowledge your older affiliation in the acknowledgment section in the end, but normally we leave that for grants, conferences or short visits.

In any case, you are a PhD student, so the correct answer to your question is: *ask your supervisor* ;)